# Can't insert multiple rows into SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, syntax, insert

I'm trying to read a .sql file into SQLite, but I'm getting syntax errors because the file was dumped from MySQL, which can add multiple entries at once, but I'm using SQLite v3.7.7, which can't read more than one entry to a table at a time with the VALUES command.

My understanding is that I either need to upgrade SQLite, or somehow modify the file to read in one entry at a time into the tables.  Please note I'm dealing with tens of thousands of entries, so inserting the UNION SELECT command probably won't be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least SQLite 3.7.11 to use the VALUES syntax you're interested in. But `mysqldump` has about 100 [command-line options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html). And one of them, `--skip-extended-insert`, can disable extended inserts. (So you get one INSERT statement per row.) Read the mysqldump documentation, and run the dump again with options that better fit your target.

Or better yet, look at the [list of SQLite converter tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools).

Comment: I don't have MySQL; I only have the dumped file. Any chance you could tell me how to get SQLite 3.7.11 or newer?

Comment: You can download and install MySQL, load your dump into it, and dump again using other command-line options. (Maybe. If you have some login credentials for that database. Not sure whether you realized that.) If you're on a Unix(ish) system, I'd try to update SQLite from my package manager first. Failing that, download and compile the source from the [SQLite download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html/). (You probably want the download that includes the amalgamation, the configure script, and the makefile.) Current version is 3.7.13.